# How to apply the resulting removed outliers on the dataset using boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

Good day,

I am using `boxplot` to remove the outliers from my dataset:

```
outliers <- boxplot(dataset, outline=FALSE);
```

Now as outliers variable has all information, how do I apply the removal on dataset? Does `boxplot` do that inplace?

Thank you,

Comment: Please see how outliers are typically calculated: [What are outliers in the data?](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section1/prc16.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The values that `boxplot` considers to be outliers are stored in `outliers$out`. So, assuming that your `dataset` contains values in a column named `value`, you could remove them like this:

```
dataset[!dataset$value %in% outliers$out, ]
```

or if `dataset` had only the one column:

```
dataset[!dataset$value %in% outliers$out, , drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use this -

```
x[!x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out]
```